# Add CSV to Access database from Excel

Tags: ms-access, excel, csv, import, vba

I have multiple tables that are saved in CSV format:

- table1.csv
- table2.csv
- table3.csv

I would like to import all of the files into one Access (database.mdb) database.
I.e. as the result there should be 1 MS Access file with table1, table2, table3.

Is it possible to do this operation from Excel's VBA?

There is a command:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "dTT_DSC_Bucket_Alert_Thresholds", _
    "table1", "C:\Users\MEEE\Desktop\dumps\New folder\files\table1.csv", True
```

But it works only from Access itself. I need to be able to somehow connect to MDB from excel, and then do the import for each file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but we need to add to your Excel  --  Tools / References / MSAccess

Then create a MDB  (e.g.  StackCSV.mdb,  or  database.mdb) in some folder.

then add this code to your excel --

```
Option Explicit

Sub doit()

    ' Create an instance of the Access application object.
    Dim objAccess As Access.Application
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")


    ' Check that this is the path on YOUR PC for
    Const conPATH = "C:\donPablo\StackOverFlow\StackCSV.mdb"
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase conPATH
    objAccess.Visible = True

     ' do the Transfer
    objAccess.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "", _
    "table1", "C:\donPablo\StackOverFlow\StackCSV.csv", True

    ' close out the mdb
    objAccess.Quit
    Set objAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```